# Delete only one channel - Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I made this command to delete a channel starting with the word Ticket (for example) but it deletes all the channels starting with this word, is there a way to make it delete only the channel where it was called?

My code (in a cog) :

@commands.command()

```
async def close(self, ctx):
    for channel in ctx.guild.text_channels:
        if channel.name.startswith(("ticket","recrutement","partenariat","tickets","partenariats")):
            await chat_exporter.quick_export(ctx)
            await asyncio.sleep(10)
            await channel.send("Suppression...")
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
            await channel.delete()
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Indeed, if you made a piece of code aiming to "delete [a] channel starting with the word Ticket", it will delete __all channels__ matching your condition...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line right here: `if channel.name.startswith(("ticket","recrutement","partenariat","tickets","partenariats")):`, You are saying that if the channel name `startswith` (a built-in string function) any one of the values, then do stuff. If you want it to be more specific than that, use in, to match it exactly: `if channel.name in ("ticket","recrutement","partenariat","tickets","partenariats"):` Instead of just checking if the first letters of each channel name match, it now checks the entire channel name. This should fix the problem you described.